# Solve nonlinear system in maple

Tags: maple

I want to solve the system $A - B = C$ to $A$, with $A$, $B$, $C$ matrices. And the variables in the matrix $B$ and $C$ are a combination of the variables in $A$. How can I do this?
Because LinearSolve doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Equate](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Equate&term=Equate) command to produce a set of equations that relation to the given elementwise equality.

For example, `Equate(A-B, C)`.

Then you might use `solve` or `fsolve` on the set of equations that result from calling `Equate`.